# Is it OK to use dictionaries when I don't need to quickly access their values?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Normally, I use a dictionary like a list, but with a key of a different type. I like the ability to quickly access individual items in the dictionary without having to loop through it until I find the item with the right property (because the property I'm looking for is in the Key).

But there is another possible use of a dictionary. I could just use the Key to store property A and the Value to store property B without ever using the dictionary's special functionality. For example, I could store a list of persons just by storing the forename in the key and the family name in the value (let's assume, for the sake of simplicity, that there won't ever be two people with the same forename, because I just couldn't come up with an better example). I would only use that dictionary to loop through it in a foreach loop and add items to it (no removing, sorting or accessing individual items). There would actually be no difference to using a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` from using a `Dictionary<string, string>` (at least not in the example that I gave - I know that I could e. g. store multiple items wiht the same key in the list).

So, to sum it up, what should I do when I don't need to use the special functionalities a dictionary provides and just use it to store something that has exactly two properties:

- use a `Dictionary<,>`
- use a `List<KeyValuePair<,>`
- use a `List<MyType>` with `MyType` being a custom class that contains the two properties and a constructor.

Comment: i don't get the problem

Comment: When you don't need a dictionary, don't use it. Unless you need it. Then do.

Comment: Usually you can use just `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but its name is too long so most of the people use `Dictionary<string,string>` here, or `StringDictionary` what is even shorter.

Comment: But correct way I think will be to use `List<Tuple<string,string>>`.

Comment: @abatishchev *Usually you can use just `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but its name is too long so most of the people use `Dictionary<string,string>`* Ridiculous. That's not why people use `Dictionary`. It is an map data structure. When you need to access an element with a key efficiently O(1) `Dictionary` is used, **not** because `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` is big.  and also `List<Tuple<string,string>>` is not a best fit. When you're reading a code which uses `Tuple`, how sure you're that what is inside the `Tuple`?

Comment: Don't abuse a key value pair for this. For instance, you can't simultaneously store "Johannes Moser" and "Johannes Hahn" if you do this. A list of tuples would be better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't use dictionaries for that.

If you don't want to create a class for this purpose, use something like `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>`. But keep in mind a custom class will be both more readable and more flexible.

Here's the reason: it will be *much* more easy to read your code if you use proper data structures. Using a dictionary will only confuse the reader, and you'll have problems the day a duplicate key shows up.

If someone reads your code and sees a `Dictionary` being used, he will assume you really mean to use a map-like structure. Your code should be clear and your *intent* should be obvious when reading it.

Comment: +1, You said whatever I was about to say.. And I strongly recommend creating new class with meaningful names and self explanatory property names. Say no no for a `Tuple` `Item1` and `Item2` doesn't talks much about what they are..

Comment: Not knowing C#, what is `KeyValuePair` that the OP had in his list? Are there benefits of `Tuple` over it (apart from being clearer)?

Comment: @Bergi [`KeyValuePair<TKey ,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) is a simple structure which contains two properties: `Key` and `Value`. In contrast, `Tuple<,>` contains `Item1` and `Item2`. If you happen to enumerate a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you'll end up with a sequence of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` items: `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. As the OP manipulates dictionaries, he automatically gets `KeyValuePair` objects out of it.

Comment: OK, so it's only the property names of the quite same "simple structure"; and maybe some enumeration syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you're **concerned** with performance you should probably store the data in a `List`. A `Dictionary` has lots of internal overhead. Both memory as well as CPU.

If you're just concerned with **readability**, chose the data structure that best captures your intent. If you are storing key-value pairs (for example, custom fields in a bug tracker issue) then use a `Dictionary`. If you are just storing items without them having some kind of logical key, use a `List`.

It takes little work to create a **custom class** to use as an item in a `List`. Using a `Dictionary` just because it gives you a `Key` property for each item is a misuse of that data structure. It is easy to create a custom class that also has a `Key` property.

Answer (score 2):

Use `List<MyType>` where MyType includes all the values.

The problem with the dictionary approach is that it's not flexible. If you later decide to add middle names, you'll need to redesign your whole data structure, rather than just adding another field to MyType.